# Bibliography in other language than rest of document

Tags: biblatex, languages

How can I change Russian language only in list of references? I want to change "и" to "and" and "с." to "P."

I have

> S. Advani, J. Torok и J. Lee. General solutions for pistonlike displacement of compressible fluids in porous media //. Journal of energy resources technology.– 1985. – V. 107. – N. 4. – с. 523—526.

I want

> S. Advani, J. Torok and J. Lee. General solutions for pistonlike displacement of compressible fluids in porous media //. Journal of energy resources technology.– 1985. – V. 107. – N. 4. – P. 523—526.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}

\large
\def\der#1#2{{\partial #1\over \partial #2}}
% Alternative geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm}
\geometry{right=1.cm}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\hyphenation{frame-work}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[c]{{\thepage}}
\fancyheadoffset{-87.5mm}
\fancyfootoffset{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{ 
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{\thepage}}


\RequirePackage{caption}
%\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{defffis}{ -- } 
%\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centering, labelsep=defffis, format=plain} 
%\captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright, labelsep=defffis, format=plain, singlelinecheck=false} 
\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Рисунок}} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\bfseries\centering}
  { \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter }{14pt}{\large}
  
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\centering}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage[ 
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric
]{biblatex} 
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{% 
bibencoding=utf8, 
bibwarn=true, 
sortlocale=de_DE, 
isbn=false, 
url=false, 
doi=false, 
eprint=false, 
clearlang=true, 
maxbibnames=99, 
firstinits=true, 
sorting=none, 
} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1 //\space}
%\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space //\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{{--\addnbspace N.\addnbspace #1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
   page = {{}{}}, 
   pages = {{}{}}, 
} 
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\adddot \addspace \text{--} \addspace}%точка-тире после издателя
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\adddot\space \text{--}\space \text{V.} }% точка-тире после года
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}% 
 \setunit{\addcolon\space }%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eid}%
}
\newbibmacro*{issue+date}{
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\adddot \space \addperiod \space \text{--}\space }% 
\addbibresource{mybib.bib} 

\begin{document} 

Text~ 
\cite{advani1985general}

\begingroup
\let\itshape\upshape
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

.bib:

```
@article{advani1985general,
  title={General solutions for pistonlike displacement of compressible fluids in porous media},
  author={Advani, SH and Torok, JS and Lee, JK},
  journal={Journal of energy resources technology},
  volume={107},
  number={4},
  pages={523--526},
  year={1985},
  publisher={American Society of Mechanical Engineers}
}
```

Comment: What is needed here is to identify this particular reference as English.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to do that, although I would try adding `language=(English}.` to the `bib` entry.

Comment: The two problems are independent and should be asked about in two separate questions. Separate questions are easier to answer, because one only has to focus on one aspect and are much more relevant for future visitors.

Comment: That said: `biblatex` normally uses the currently active language for the list of references. Since `babel` is loaded as `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`, the main language of your document is Russian, so `biblatex` produces a Russian bibliography. If you want an English bibliography, switch to English with `{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\printbibliography
\end{otherlanguage}}`

Comment: For your second problem, I suggest you have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gost. What you are trying to build from scratch here looks suspiciously like GOST, so you can make your life a lot easier if you just take the ready-made style.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now language is changed:)

Comment: The second question is now at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/623141/35864, so I'll edit your question to focus on the language issue only.

Answer (score 1):

By default `biblatex` adapts its output to the currently active language in your document. Since your document loads `babel` as `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}`, the main language of your document is Russian (figure/table captions as well as the table of contents and list of tables/figures will be in Russian).

When `\printbibliography` is called in your example it will adapt to the active language and typeset in Russian.

If you want an English bibliography in your otherwise Russian document, switch the language

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\printbibliography
\end{otherlanguage}}
\end{document}
```

[image: English bibliography in Russian document.]