# How to delete a symbol between article name and journal name and add new symbol in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, punctuation, languages, bibliographystyle

I have already added symbol "//" between article name and journal name, but how can I delete dot "."?

What I have:
Advani,  J.  Torok,  and  J.  Lee.  General  solutions  for  pistonlike  displacement of compressible fluids in porous media //. Journal of energy resources technology. – 1985. – V. 107. – N. 4. – pp. 523–526.

What I want:
Advani,  J.  Torok,  and  J.  Lee.  General  solutions  for  pistonlike  displacement of compressible fluids in porous media // Journal of energy resources technology. – 1985. – V. 107. – N. 4. – pp. 523–526.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
% Alternative geometry
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.5cm}
\geometry{right=1.cm}
\geometry{top=2cm}
\geometry{bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[ 
    backend=biber, 
    style=numeric
]{biblatex} 
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{% 
bibencoding=utf8, 
bibwarn=true, 
sortlocale=de_DE, 
isbn=false, 
url=false, 
doi=false, 
eprint=false, 
clearlang=true, 
maxbibnames=99, 
firstinits=true, 
sorting=none, 
} 
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1 //\space}
%\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\space //\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{date}{{#1}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{{--\addnbspace N.\addnbspace #1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{% 
   page = {{}{}}, 
   pages = {{}{}}, 
} 
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\adddot \addspace \text{--} \addspace}%точка-тире после издателя
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\adddot\space \text{--}\space \text{V.} }
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}% 
 \setunit{\addcolon\space }%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{eid}%
}
\newbibmacro*{issue+date}{
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}%
  \newunit}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\adddot \space \addperiod \space \text{--}\space }
\addbibresource{mybib.bib} 
\begin{document} 

Text~
\cite{advani1985general}
\begingroup
\let\itshape\upshape
{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\printbibliography 
\end{otherlanguage}}
\end{document}
```

.bib:

```
@article{advani1985general,
  title={General solutions for pistonlike displacement of compressible fluids in porous media},
  author={Advani, SH and Torok, JS and Lee, JK},
  journal={Journal of energy resources technology},
  volume={107},
  number={4},
  pages={523--526},
  year={1985},
  publisher={American Society of Mechanical Engineers}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking it is not a good idea to include leading or trailing punctuation in a field format declaration as in

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1 //\space}
```

In your example document you have discovered the main reason why: It can lead to undesirable punctuation clashes because `biblatex` does not know that you added punctuation via the field format.

A better way to resolve this would be to add the punctuation with `\printunit` in the relevant bibmacro.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{title}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{title}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{subtitle}}
  }
    {}
    {\printtext[title]{%
       \printfield[titlecase]{title}%
       \setunit{\subtitlepunct}%
       \printfield[titlecase]{subtitle}}%
     \newunit}%
  \printfield{titleaddon}%
  \printunit{\addspace//\space}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{} 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{advani1985general,
  title   = {General Solutions for Pistonlike Displacement
             of Compressible Fluids in Porous Media},
  author  = {Advani, S. H. and Torok, J. S. and Lee, J. K.},
  journal = {Journal of Energy Resources Technology},
  volume  = {107},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {523--526},
  year    = {1985},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,advani1985general}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: S. H. Advani, J. S. Torok and J. K. Lee. General Solutions for Pistonlike Displacement of Compressible Fluids in Porous Media // Journal of Energy Resources Technology 107.4 (1985), pp. 523–526.]

That all said, the style you seem to want looks extremely similar to GOST 7.0.5-2008. So I strongly suggest you have a look at [`biblatex-gost`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-gost)'s `style=gost-numeric,`

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=gost-numeric]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{advani1985general,
  title   = {General Solutions for Pistonlike Displacement
             of Compressible Fluids in Porous Media},
  author  = {Advani, S. H. and Torok, J. S. and Lee, J. K.},
  journal = {Journal of Energy Resources Technology},
  volume  = {107},
  number  = {4},
  pages   = {523--526},
  year    = {1985},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,advani1985general}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Advani S. H., Torok J. S., Lee J. K. General Solutions for Pistonlike Displacement of Compressible Fluids in Porous Media // Journal of Energy Resources Technology. — 1985. — Vol. 107, no. 4. — P. 523–526.]

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to use gost style, but I didn't like it. Sometimes the reference starts with article name, not author name and there are also other problems... But thanks a lot for your answer, it helped!!!!